# Error in update array list query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am sending 2 arraylist from android to php through url .
 Mysql contains test table with two columns menuimage, menuname. I want to update menu name only but it is updating only first row of menuname in mysql database

Tried so far-

```
          <?php
$old_menu_names=explode(',',preg_replace('/^.*\[(.*)\].*$/','$1',trim($_POST['menuname'], '[]')));
$new_menu_names=explode(',',preg_replace('/^.*\[(.*)\].*$/','$1',trim($_POST['editmainmenu'], '[]')));
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "MobixMySQL");
mysql_select_db("cozydine");
foreach ($old_menu_names as $key => $old_name) {
    $new_name = mysql_real_escape_string($new_menu_names[$key]);
    $old_name  = mysql_real_escape_string($old_menu_names[$key]);
    echo $new_name;
    mysql_query("UPDATE `mainmenu` SET `menuname` = '$new_name' WHERE menuname = '$old_name'")
    or die('Error' . mysql_error());
    echo "Updated";
   }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because their in only one old name in the db that is now replaced with new name. if you want to update all the values of rows with new do something like this

```
"UPDATE `mainmenu` SET `menuname` = '$new_name' WHERE menuname IN ($unexploded_old_menu_names)"
```

EDITED

in your loop instead of using key for new name use a counter

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($old_menu_names as $key => $old_name)
{
$new_name = mysql_real_escape_string($new_menu_names[$i]);
$old_name  = mysql_real_escape_string($old_menu_names[$key]);
echo $new_name;
mysql_query("UPDATE `mainmenu` SET `menuname` = '$new_name' WHERE menuname = '$old_name'")
or die('Error' . mysql_error());
echo "Updated";
$i++;
```

}

Because key might not be working for new names array.

Comment: i put ur update query they show like this error ErrorYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1..please tell me how to solve

Comment: why ur using $unexploded_old_menu_names this variable on where condition..please tell me how to solve the above error

Comment: This means that if there are let suppose 3 items i want to change with 1 name i will do this  UPDATE `mainmenu` SET `menuname` = '$new_name' WHERE menuname IN ('a','b','c') it will replace a b c with new name

Comment: echo $new_name; it prints all edited values but it only updated first value

Comment: echo $new_name; means it printed newvalues but it update only first row remaining rows are not updated please see

Comment: first print_r($_POST) to see how many values you are getting . Are the more then one? Is the loop running only once or more?